# Using DISTINC within aggregate functions in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is there a way for me to simplify the following code: `WITH DISTINCT n.prop as distinct_prop RETURN COUNT(distinct_prop)`

As you can see, I use an aggregation function with distinct values. Can I somehow "skip" the `WITH` clause? It seems kind of redundant, but without it the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With aggregation functions, you can use DISTINCT, so RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n.prop)
Check the docs here -> https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/return#10-returning-unique-results